# Error KeyError: False In my alarm Function

Tags: python, function

Basically this is my problem (testing how dictionaries work)
I'm just trying to do a simple alarm function that should go like this:

setAlarm(True, True) -> false

setAlarm(False, True) -> false

setAlarm(False, False) -> false

setAlarm(True, False) -> true

```
def set_alarm(employed, vacation):
    alarm={True : False}
    if alarm[employed]==vacation:
        return True
    return False
```

Instead it gives me the `KeyError: False` ever since the first statement is False

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You haven't defined ```False``` in your ```alarm``` dictionary.  So ```alarm[False]```` produces the error.

Comment: I was struggling for nothing. Sorry. Just wanting to test how dictionaries work.

Comment: It's not nothing if you learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this is the best solution... but you can add a try-expect to make it works! This (Expect) will automatically return false when a KeyError is given!
This is the code and it works me!

```
`def set_alarm(employed, vacation):
    alarm={True : False}
    try:
        if alarm[employed]==vacation:
            return True
    except KeyError:
        return False

print(set_alarm(False, False))`
```

I hope that It works you too!! Greetings!

Comment: Thanks!! I had no idea I could do that.

Comment: It's typically better practice to test if the key is in the dictionary with an `if` `in` statement